# Computer Vision: How to find how many rows(lines) of bounding boxes in an invoice?

Tags: python-3.x, list, image-processing, computer-vision

- I have multiple invoices which I already found the coordinates of the bounding boxes in each invoice.
- Here is the y coordinate(each small list is the y coordinate of the bounding box-ymin and ymax):

```
      [[4, 43],
      [9, 47],
      [76, 122],
      [30, 74],
      [10, 47],
      [81, 125],
      [84, 124],
      [47, 90],
      [1, 38]]
```

I want to determine which bounding box is on the first line, which is on the second and which is on the third depending the y-coordinates. More generally, how can I find the range of the first row, second, or third?

[image: Here is an example of an invoice]

There are multiple invoices that have more rows or less rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is sensitive to the threshold which you might need to adjust depending to the amount of text in each line!

- Firstly, segment the lines depending on the presence, and the amount of text(black pixels).
- Secondly, find lines borders to compare your bounding boxes with.
- Finally, do the comparison between your bounding boxes indices, and segmented line indices.

> output:

```
[17, 40, 53, 79, 95, 117]
box [4,43]  belongs to line 1
box [9,47]  belongs to line 1
box [76,122]  belongs to line 3
box [10,47]  belongs to line 1
box [81,125]  belongs to line 3
box [84,124]  belongs to line 3
box [47,90]  belongs to line 2
```

> Code:

```py
import cv2

# Read the image
orig = cv2.imread('input.jpg', 0)[:,15:]

# The detected boxes
boxes = [[4, 43],
[9, 47],
[76, 122],
[30, 74],
[10, 47],
[81, 125],
[84, 124],
[47, 90],
[1, 38]]

# make a deep copy
img = orig.copy()

# quantify the black pixels in each line
summ = img.sum(axis=1)

# Threshold
th = summ.mean()

img[summ>th, :] = 0
img[summ<=th,:] = 1

rows = []
for y in range(img.shape[0]-1):
    if img[y,0]>img[y+1,0] or img[y,0]<img[y+1,0]:
        rows.append(y)

# sort lines indices. 
rows.sort()

print(rows)

# compare the indices
for box in boxes:
    for idx in range(0, len(rows), 2):
        if box[0] < rows[idx] and box[1] > rows[idx+1]:
            print("box [{},{}]".format(box[0], box[1]), " belongs to line {}".format(idx//2+1))
```

Comment: Any other way without using the cv2? I have extracted all the coordinates of the bounding boxes to a list so that I can determine the intervals of a list

Comment: @HungNguyen you can read the image using numpy instead, I'm using 'OpenCV' only to read the image, you can replace it with any other library to read the image.